# Is there a process with pid 0 linux?

Tags: linux, pid

Is there a process with pid 0 linux? Also is there any negative pids? This is just out of curiosity :D

Comment: You'll find your answer in the above question – much better explained than what I could come up with :)

Comment: `kill -1` kills all processes, so the answer to the second question is *no*.

Comment: @Dennis But the reason for no negative PIDs is not `kill`… it's the way the kernel allocates PIDs.

Comment: @shlck: kill's behavior is – of course – effect, not cause. I was trying to say in my previous comment that, if the kernel allocated negative PIDS, kill would have been written differently.